# I need assistance with a typeError in python 3 im new to coding/python so im a little confused

Tags: python-3.x

Help i keep getting the error: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

```
player_pos = [x,y]

screen.fill(background_color)
if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < height:
    enemy_pos[1] += 15
else:
    enemy_pos[1] = 0
```

Comment: Where is `enemy_pos` initialized?

Comment: Seems like the issue is that `enemy_pos` is a tuple, unlike `player_pos`. Consider looking at where it is defined, or include that in your question.

Comment: ok thanks ill try that

Comment: In python there are two kinds of objects, **mutable objects** and **immutable objects**. Objects such as tuple, int, float etc. are immutable, that is, you can't change the values of these objects once you create them, if you need a different one, just create another one, whereas list, dict etc. are mutable, it is these objects that you can assign to after creation.